# Excel VBA Macro calling multiple Macros based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that calls different macros and changes cell colors. So, if a cell in the entire column D (D4:D446) equals a certain value, THIS macro will call a separate macro associated with that value.

In other words, What I want is, for example, if any or multiple cells in range D7:D446 = "1000ABC", "1000EFG", or "1000HIJ", any/all cells in column F7:F446 will turn red to indicate to the user that they need to click on that cell in F7:F446 and when the user clicks on that cell in column F, it will call the correct macro I already created.

Example: if cell D25="1000EFG" cell F25 will turn red and when the user clicks on cell F25, it will take him to the macro associated with the value 1000EFG. I have already created the other macros, I just need to tie them together with this functionality. (These values are hypothetical)

The issues I am having is that no matter the values in cell D, when I click on the associated cell in the F column, it will take me to one macro and one macro only (not the correct macro associated with the value in cell D). I also am unsure of the syntax on how to change a cell color red depending on a value. I can't seem to tie these functionalities  together in one macro. I will post the code I have tried below. **ANY** help is very much appreciated. You guys are awesome, Thanks!

```
Sub gotorefs()

For Each c In Worksheets("JE").Range("D7:D446")

    If c.Value = "1000GP" Then
        Call gotoref1
     Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Select.ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "1000MM" Then
        Call gotoref2
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

 ElseIf c.Value = "19FEST" Then
        Call gotoref3
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "20IEDU" Then
        Call gotoref4
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

 ElseIf c.Value = "20ONLC" Then
        Call gotoref5
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "20PART" Then
        Call gotoref6
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "20PRDV" Then
        Call gotoref7
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "20SPPR" Then
        Call gotoref8
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "22DANC" Then
        Call gotoref9
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "22LFLC" Then
        Call gotoref10
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "22MEDA" Then
        Call gotoref11
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "530CCH" Then
        Call gotoref12
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "60PUBL" Then
        Call gotoref13
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "74GA01" Then
        Call gotoref14
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "74GA17" Then
        Call gotoref15
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "74GA99" Then
        Call gotoref16
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

ElseIf c.Value = "78REDV" Then
        Call gotoref17
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

Next c

End sub
```

Comment: You have syntax error here `Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Select.ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`. Apart of that, your loop tries to call all the subs in turn on the rows, while you said you want to do it only when the user clicks on the `F` cell.

Comment: I should clarify, if, for example, cell D25 = "1000GP", once that value is entered into cell D25, I would like F25 to turn red automatically. Once the user clicks on the red colored cell F25, it will take them to the macor associated with the value "1000GP", which is macro "gotoref1".

Comment: Then your code should be split in two parts. The above chunk should only set the colors in column F. another one, a `Worksheet_Change` event should capture the click on cell F and call the appropriate routine. Besides, I advice you to use *some naming convention* for those routines, such as `Sub1000GP`, this will make life easier for you later.

Comment: Also, as you can probably tell, I am unsure of the syntax in order to execute this functionality. I haven't had much luck with researching it online and this is my first experience with vba.

Comment: So, as of right now, I have the "sub gotorefs()". Do you suggest I keep this sub, and just add a private sub underneath that changes the cell color, THEN in the same sub gotorefs(), under the private sub, create the method that calls the macros associated with the different values?

Comment: Or, should I create the worksheet change that changes the cell colors and the macro that call the different macros inside of it, separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it by handling the `Worksheet_Change event`. To do so, add this to your **worksheet "JE" code module**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim c As Range: Set c = Range("D7:D446")
  For Each c In c.Cells
    Select Case c.Value
      Case "1000GP", "1000MM", "19FEST", "20IEDU", "20ONLC", "20PART", "20PRDV", "20SPPR", "22DANC", "22LFLC", "22MEDA", "530CCH", "60POUBL", "74GA01", "74GA17", "74GA99", "78REDV"
        Cells(c.row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      Case Else
        Cells(c.row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End Select
  Next c
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
    Cancel = True
    ' Now call the appropriate routine according to column C
    Select Case Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
      Case "1000GP": gotoref1
      Case "1000MM": gotoref2
      Case "19FEST": gotoref3
      Case "20PRDV": gotoref4
      Case "20IEDU": gotoref5
      Case "20ONLC": gotoref6
      Case "20PART": gotoref7
      Case "20SPPR": gotoref8
      Case "22DANC": gotoref9
      Case "22LFLC": gotoref10
      Case "22MEDA": gotoref11
      Case "530CCH": gotoref12
      Case "60POUBL": gotoref13
      Case "74GA01": gotoref14
      Case "74GA17": gotoref15
      Case "74GA99": gotoref16
      Case "78REDV": gotoref17
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

A final advice, this way of dispatching to so many different routines is tedious and error prone. You might think of following some *naming convention* to make the called routines match with the values. For example, if you name your routines like `Ref_1000GP`, `Ref_1000MM` etc, then the second `Select Case` statement would reduce to a single line like the following:

```
CallByName "Ref_" & Target.Offset(0, -3).Value2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciate your input. I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The top part worked, the cells turn red when those vales are inputted into the D column. The second part, starting with the If Target.Column=6, etc.. that part of the code is to call the other, different macros associated with those values, correct? If so, that second part is not working. That is, when those 17 values are inputted into column D, and the corresponding columns F turn red, they are not "clickable" and do not navigate to those macros. Would you happen to know why that is? I also keep getting runtime error subscript out of range & runtime error 424 object.. I can't thank you enough

Comment: @Andrew I just realized that the `F` cells need to be handled vi another event, not the worksheet_change event. I can suggest a solution that I have used often and that is based on "double-click" than on click. Do you want that? See the edited code for that.

Comment: p.s. if the double-click option is not what you want, the other option would be `Selection_Change`, but then the routine would be triggered whether the selection happens from the keyboard or from the mouse click.

Comment: thanks so much for your input. I think the double-click functionality would suit my users the best. I'll make that adjustment to my code and try t out tomorrow. I'll be sure to update you as to how it comes out. Thanks again! I very much appreciate it.

Comment: I implemented the code you suggested and the cells in column F do not turn red when one of the 17 values in column D are inputted and cells in column F aren't clickable and I continue to get an "Object Required" error message. I tried googling what object required means but I am having some trouble with it. Here is my code:

Comment: `Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("D7:D446"))
    Select Case c.Value
      Case "1000GP", "1000MM", "19FEST", "20IEDU", "20ONLC", "20PART", "20PRDV", "20SPPR", "22DANC", "22LFLC", "22MEDA", "530CCH", "60POUBL", "74GA01", "74GA17", "74GA99", "78REDV"
      
        Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      Case Else
        Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End Select
  Next c
End Sub`

Comment: Part I: `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
      Cancel = True
      ' Now call the appropriate routine according to column C`

Comment: Part II: `Select Case Target.Offset(0, -3).Value2
        Case "1000GP":    gotoref1
        Case "1000MM":   gotoref2
        Case "19FEST":   gotoref3
           'etc...
      End Select
  End If
End Sub`

Comment: @Andrew I see. With `Offset(,-3)` we were checking column `C` not `D`. changed to `Offset(,-2)`. Other change is that we had to check the `Intersect` for `Nothing` before iterating on it. I corrected these and posted complete and tested code. Hope it helps.

Comment: One last thing, for this `Worksheet_Change` event to work as intended, the cells in column `D` must be edited directly. It wont fire the way we expect it if these cells actually have formulas. If that's the case, we need to move that code (with a slight modification) into a `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: Thanks! I have adjusted my code a little bit. I will try to post it in parts like I did before. You are right, the values in the D column are derived from a formula which reads a longer value in the C column: MID(C7,16,6). I still need the cells in the D column to have the ability to be clicked and when the user clicks a red colored cell in the D column it navigates them to the correct macro associated with the value in the D column (ex: if value in D25 = "1000GP", when the user clicks on cell F25, it will take them to the macro gotoref1). That part I haven't been able to get yet.

Comment: `Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7:D446")) Is Nothing Then
      Dim c As Range
      For Each c In Target
          Select Case c.Value
              Case "1000GP", "1000MM", "19FEST", "20IEDU", "20PART", "20PRDV", "20SPPR", "22DANC", "22LFLC", "22MEDA", "530CCH", "60POUBL", "74GA01", "74GA17", "74GA99", "78REDV"
                  Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
              Case Else
                 Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
          End Select
      Next c
 End If
End Sub`

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
      Cancel = True
      ' Now call the appropriate routine according to column C
      Select Case Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
        Case "1000GP": gotoref1
        Case "1000MM": gotoref2
        Case "19FEST": gotoref3
        Case "78REDV": gotoref17
      End Select
  End If
End Sub`

Comment: that code adjustment worked. However, The cells in the F column are not turning red automatically, I have to double click inside the D cells, to get the formula to show, then hit enter. That is when the F cells turn red. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: I told you about that, the cells in C change following a formula so when the `C` cells change the `Target` doe not intersect column `D`. For quick change modify the following `Set c = Intersect(Target, Range("D7:D446"))` To `Set c = Range("D7:D446")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seemed to work. One final functionality I was hoping to add to this is, after users are taken to the appropriate macro, they are able to double-click on any value in the A column of that macro, and that value will go back and populate the cell in the F column and change the cell color from red, back to no fill (white background). Any suggestion on how to accomplish that?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Andrew That seems to be fit for another question, (I did not quite get it in this format) so please feel free to ask a new question and try to add enough details.